# I need some direction on accessing a salesforce sandbox through an api

Tags: soap, wsdl, salesforce, sandbox, force.com

can someone with salesforce API integration help me understand the requirements to access a client's Sandbox? I hired a programmer but he seems to be having a hard time accessing the sandbox and I want to try to help by guiding him in the right direction? Client provided us with the following credentials for the sandbox.

Target URL:  http://xxx.my.salesforce.com
Username:   user@clientdomain.com.beta
password:   xxxxxxx
token:   gave us a token to access through API.

Your help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the client's sandbox instance? The Force.com IDE? Chatter for Desktop? The website? Particular programming language SDK?

Answer (score 0):

To connect via SOAP/WSDL, you'll find lots of great instructions and examples on developer force website: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector

You'll need to obtain a copy of WSDL from the sandbox instance, you can login to their sandbox instance via https://test.salesforce.com and using the provided username and password. Once logged in to the test website, click Your Name | Setup | App Setup | Develop | API. You will then be on a page with various options to generate an appropriate WSDL.

Note, these instructions assume you're using Java, but provide step-by-step instructions to get a SOAP client up and running.